# Verilog Generate statements: Syntax error near "<=": unexpected <=

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

I am very new to Verilog, and I found the need to use "generate loops" to instantiate multiple hardware blocks. In this case, I am instantiating multiple "pe" blocks, a block which performs some simple arithmetic.

Code is shown below:

```
// intermediate signals
reg init_temp;
reg [D_W-1:0] in_a_temp;
reg [D_W-1:0] in_b_temp;
reg valid_D_in_temp;

genvar i, j;
generate
        for (i=0; i<N; i=i+1) begin : pe_generate_i
                for (j=0; j<N; j=j+1) begin : pe_generate_j
                        if ((i == 0) & (j == 0)) begin
                                valid_D_in_temp <= (pixel_cntr_A == M-1);
                                init_temp <= (pixel_cntr_A == M-1);
                                in_a_temp <= A[0];
                                in_b_temp <= B[0];
                        end else if (j == 0) begin
                                in_a_temp <= A[i];
                                valid_D_in_temp <= valid_D[i-1][j];
                        end else if (i == 0) begin
                                in_b_temp <= B[j];
                        end else begin
                                valid_D_in_temp <= valid_D[i][j-1];
                                init_temp <= gg;
                        end

                        pe pe_inst (
                            .clk(clk),
                            .rst(rst),
                            .init(init_temp),
                            .in_a(in_a_temp),
                            .in_b(in_b_temp),
                            .valid_D_in(valid_D_in_temp),
                            .out_sum(),
                            .out_b(),
                            .out_a(),
                            .valid_D(),
                            .init_out()
                        );
                end
        end
endgenerate
```

A syntax error arises in the first non-blocking statement:
valid_D_in_temp <= (pixel_cntr_A == M-1);

Error:

```
# ** Error: (vlog-13069) systolic.sv(37): near "<=": syntax error, unexpected <=.
# ** Error: systolic.sv(37): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'valid_D_in_temp'. Is there a missing '::'?
```

Can anybody suggest what the problem might be?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can only use `<=` inside an `initial` or `always` process block.

If you want to have logic inside your `generate` block in addition to module instantiations, you need to wrap it in an `always @* ...` or use `assign ...` statements.

Comment: And if you do use an always block, you shod use blocking assignments (simple = sign) and not non-blocking (the left arrow <=, which is generally reserved for sequential logic).

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.

You should see a generate for loop as a "please **instance** the following code multiple times" followed by the code to instance.

Thus an assignment should be that:

```
assign valid_D_in_temp <= (pixel_cntr_A == M-1);
assign init_temp <= (pixel_cntr_A == M-1);
// etc.
```

But that code is wrong too as it uses non blocking assigns `<=` while an assign should use blocking `=`. Also you can't use `if` very well with that.

So at the moment your code is a mixture of code that should probably be in an 'always' statement and assignments which should be outside an 'always' statement. I don't know what you are trying to do so I can't tell you how the code really should look like.

I hope you are aware that the `pe pe_inst (` block will be instantiated (repeated) N*N times....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I definitely want to instantiate pe  N*N times. All that logic above the "pe pe_inst (" line of code is to specify which signals will be driving the inputs to the pe_instances. Thus, I will definitely change non-blocking assignments to assign statements (don't know why I initially put non-blocking statements)

Comment: The `if`/`else` are actually ok to be used in the generate block as they are using the genvars only (parameters can be used also) - whether they infer the intended logic I haven't checked. But they should be using `assign =` as you say, or the `always @*` from the other answer.